# Galaxy vs Cancer Genomics Cloud

Tags: cloud

I want to use cloud computing services to analyze my oncological RNA-seq data.

I came across **Galaxy** and **Cancer Genomics Cloud** as two cloud computing platforms which are used by the research community.

Can someone give me the pros and cons of using either **Galaxy** or **Cancer Genomics Cloud**.

Comment: Good question and I get the idea its about cancer, could you state your specific project/requirements please?

Comment: So I am trying to analyze RNA Seq data from Fastq files til differential expression of genes. My P.I. wants me to use either Galaxy or Cancer Genomics Cloud from Seven Bridges Genomics

Answer (score 0):

OP update reveals the data is RNA-seq transcript abundance, that is very different from identifying novel driver mutations. So the stuff below isn't relevant.

---

Just to point out the Broad Institute has been using Google Cloud Platform (GCP) for years and they must be amongst the leaders in processing next gen sequencing data on cancer oncogenesis. They do have specific GCP pipelines available via Google.

I've been tracking their work for sometime because of potential 'cross-over'. It is kinda impressive, albeit there are a few things they (excessively) over complicate.

Just to throw it out there, and it depends what you mean by 'data', if I was processing 'driver mutations' in NGS there would be no question I'd use GCP under the Broad Institutes pipeline (they've changed its name, but you can just email them). So just to labor (labour) the point it depends whatever you mean by 'data'

Comment: Thank you so much for that explanation but my P.I. wants me to analyze Fastq files using either Galaxy or Seven Bridges Genomic's Cancer Genomics Cloud.

Comment: Sorry can't help, have updated the question though.